# Duplicate rows when joining three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014, and I've got a problem with a query. I've got three tables. A `Report` consists of ten each of `ClothingObservation` and `HygieneObservation`. The way I do this is by referencing the `ReportId` of `Report` in ten rows each of the two types of observations, for 20 observations per report in total. I want to select all the rows of one report. When I try to do this, I get 100 rows. My goal is to get 10 rows, or 20 rows with `NULL` values. This is for testing purposes at the moment, so `Report` contains just 1 row, and `ClothingObservation` and `HygieneObservation` contains 10 rows each, all referencing the `ReportId` of the one existing report.

My tables, details omitted for clarity:

```
CREATE TABLE HygieneObservation
(
    HygieneObservationId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    ...
    ReportId int NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE ClothingObservation
(
    ClothingObservationId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    ...
    ReportId int NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Report
(
    ReportId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Period Date NOT NULL,
    Reporter nvarchar(8) NOT NULL,
    DepartmentId int NOT NULL
)
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    Report.ReportId, 
    Report.Period, 
    Report.Reporter, 
    Report.DepartmentId, 

    ClothingObservation.ClothingObservationId,
    HygieneObservation.HygieneObservationId

FROM Report

LEFT JOIN ClothingObservation ON
    (ClothingObservation.ReportId = Report.ReportId)
LEFT JOIN HygieneObservation ON
    (HygieneObservation.ReportId = Report.ReportId)

GROUP BY
    Report.ReportId,
    Period,
    Reporter,
    DepartmentId,

    ClothingObservation.ClothingObservationId,
    HygieneObservation.HygieneObservationId
```

This gives me 100 rows, which I understand is because each row in `ClothingObservation` is matched to each row in `HygieneObservation`. I thought that using `GROUP BY` would cause duplicates to be removed, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Any hints?

Edit: Here's my data right now (details omitted).

`Report:`

```
ReportId    Period     Reporter DepartmentId
----------- ---------- -------- ------------
1           2016-05-01 username 1
```

`ClothingObservation:`

```
ClothingObservationId ... ReportId
--------------------- ... -----------
1                     ... 1
2                     ... 1
3                     ... 1
4                     ... 1
5                     ... 1
6                     ... 1
7                     ... 1
8                     ... 1
9                     ... 1
10                    ... 1
```

`HygieneObservation:`

```
HygieneObservationId ... ReportId
-------------------- ... -----------
3                    ... 1
4                    ... 1
5                    ... 1
6                    ... 1
7                    ... 1
8                    ... 1
9                    ... 1
10                   ... 1
12                   ... 1
13                   ... 1
```

Edit 2: If I run these two queries, I get my desired output (again, irrelevant details omitted from result):

```
SELECT * FROM Report
    LEFT JOIN ClothingObservation ON
    (ClothingObservation.ReportId = Report.ReportId)
SELECT * FROM Report
    LEFT JOIN HygieneObservation ON
    (HygieneObservation.ReportId = Report.ReportId)

ReportId    Period     Reporter DepartmentId ClothingObservationId ...  ReportId
----------- ---------- -------- ------------ --------------------- ...- -----------
1           2016-05-01 username 1            1                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            2                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            3                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            4                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            5                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            6                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            7                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            8                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            9                     ...  1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            10                    ...  1

ReportId    Period     Reporter DepartmentId HygieneObservationId ... ReportId
----------- ---------- -------- ------------ -------------------- ... -----------
1           2016-05-01 username 1            3                    ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            4                    ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            5                    ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            6                    ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            7                    ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            8                    ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            9                    ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            10                   ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            12                   ... 1
1           2016-05-01 username 1            13                   ... 1
```

My goal is to get this output (or something like it) with one query.

Comment: Well you have to define what's supposed to do with multiple matches. If one report is referred with many observations than which observation should be displayed? Or even count of observations.

Comment: Since you select both the ClothingObservationId and HygieneObservationId, there are 10*10 possible combinations. Therefore, there are no duplicates.

Comment: @RobertKock that's true :D I might need to rephrase...

Comment: @IvanStarostin Each report is referenced by total 20 observations. So I'd want at most 20 rows, with `NULL` values where there's no data to display. If that makes sense?

Comment: @Tobbe add required output for your report to the question.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Done! Hope this brings some clarification. Now I get *all* observations referencing the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that joining Report (1 row) to ClothingObservation (10 rows) produces 10 row (1 x 10), you then join to HygieneObservation (10 rows) which gives you 100. The reason this is happening is because after the initial join you have 10 rows with the same ReportID so the next join takes each of these 10 rows and joins to the 10 rows in HygieneObservation.

### The solution for "20 rows with NULL values":

```
SELECT 
    Report.ReportId, 
    Report.Period, 
    Report.Reporter, 
    Report.DepartmentId, 
    ClothingObservation.ClothingObservationId,
     NULL AS HygieneObservationId
FROM Report
LEFT JOIN ClothingObservation ON
    (ClothingObservation.ReportId = Report.ReportId)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    Report.ReportId, 
    Report.Period, 
    Report.Reporter, 
    Report.DepartmentId, 
    NULL AS ClothingObservationId,
    HygieneObservation.HygieneObservationId
FROM Report
LEFT JOIN HygieneObservation ON
    (HygieneObservation.ReportId = Report.ReportId)
```

How it works:
You essentially write two separate queries: one that join Report and ClothingObservation and another that joins Report to HygieneObservation. You then combine the two queries with `UNION ALL`.

### The solution for "get 10 rows"

This is complex as it involves what I call "vertical merging" or "Merge Join". Below is the query (**Update:** I have tested it).

```
SELECT 
    Report.ReportId, 
    Report.Period, 
    Report.Reporter, 
    Report.DepartmentId, 

    MergedObservations.ClothingObservationId,
    MergedObservations.HygieneObservationId
FROM Report
    LEFT JOIN 
            ( SELECT COALESCE( ClothingObservation.ReportID, HygieneObservation.ReportID ) AS ReportID,
                    HygieneObservationID, ClothingObservationID -- Add appropriate columns
            FROM
                        ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ReportID ORDER BY ClothingObservationID ) AS ResultID, ReportID, ClothingObservationID
                        FROM ClothingObservation ) AS ClothingObservation
               FULL OUTER JOIN
                        ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ReportID ORDER BY HygieneObservationID  ) AS ResultID, ReportID, HygieneObservationID
                        FROM HygieneObservation ) AS HygieneObservation
                    ON ClothingObservation.ReportID = HygieneObservation.ReportID
                        AND ClothingObservation.ResultID = HygieneObservation.ResultID
            ) AS MergedObservations
        ON Report.ReportID = MergedObservations.ReportID
```

How it works:
Because ClothingObservation and HygieneObservationId are not directly related to each other and have differing number of rows per ReportID, I use a `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate a join key. I then do a "Merge Join" using ReportID and the output of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

### Sample Data

I have converted your sample data into a usable table data to test above queries.

```
CREATE TABLE Report( ReportId INT, Period DATETIME, Reporter VARCHAR( 20 ), DepartmentId INT )
CREATE TABLE ClothingObservation( ClothingObservationID INT, ReportId INT )
CREATE TABLE HygieneObservation( HygieneObservationID INT, ReportId INT )

INSERT INTO Report
VALUES( 1, '2016-05-01', 'username', 1 )

INSERT INTO ClothingObservation
VALUES
( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 1 ), ( 3, 1 ), ( 4, 1 ), ( 5, 1 ), ( 6, 1 ), ( 7, 1 ), ( 8, 1 ), ( 9, 1 ), ( 10, 1 )

INSERT INTO HygieneObservation
VALUES
( 3, 1 ), ( 4, 1 ), ( 5, 1 ), ( 6, 1 ), ( 7, 1 ), ( 8, 1 ), ( 9, 1 ), ( 10, 1 ), ( 11, 1 ), ( 12, 1 ), ( 13, 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess what I was trying to do was more complicated than I thought :) Perhaps I'll rethink how to design the database to make this type of query easier. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: As I was testing the above queries using your sample data, you posted the reply. Anyway, I have corrected the 2nd query and included test data for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use the query below:

```
SELECT
    ReportId = ISNULL(v1.ReportId, v2.ReportId),
    Period = ISNULL(v1.Period, v2.Period), 
    Reporter = ISNULL(v1.Reporter, v2.Reporter), 
    DepartmentId = ISNULL(v1.DepartmentId, v2.DepartmentId),
    v1.ClothingObservationId, 
    v2.HygieneObservationId
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY r.ReportId ORDER BY c.ClothingObservationId),
        r.ReportId, 
        r.Period, 
        r.Reporter, 
        r.DepartmentId, 
        c.ClothingObservationId
    FROM 
        Report r
        LEFT JOIN ClothingObservation c ON c.ReportId = r.ReportId) v1
FULL JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY r.ReportId ORDER BY h.HygieneObservationId),
        r.ReportId, 
        r.Period, 
        r.Reporter, 
        r.DepartmentId, 
        h.HygieneObservationId
    FROM Report r
    LEFT JOIN HygieneObservation h ON h.ReportId = r.ReportId) v2 ON v1.RowNumber = v2.RowNumber AND v1.ReportId = v2.ReportId
ORDER BY ReportId
```

Comment: Strictly speaking your query is incorect but it probably returns correct results based on sample data with only one record Report table. Your join needs to include a ReportID to ensure that Report table fields are matched in the join. Additionally window function need to partion by ReportID to allow this join to succeed.

Comment: Your right, I added records in tables and it failed. I already updated my answer.